# Aligning a pattern to connect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, patterns, alignment

So I have been trying to search it on different platforms, but there is no answer to it. And I am sorry if I am not using the right search terms.

I am creating a 23.5 cm × 4.5 cm sticker in Illustrator that has to go on a circular jar. What I want is that once the sticker is placed, it creates a seamless pattern (as in that the end and the start meet creating without breaking the pattern).

But I can't figure out a way to do that when scaling the pattern inside the object?

Is there a tool/technique that I can use that can help with that?

[image]

Comment: For 23.5x4.5cm I, honestly, would not bother with an actual pattern swatch. I'd just create the correct artwork. Or... create the pattern tile *at final size* so one tile fills the artwork area entirely. That pattern, in itself is not complicated.

Comment: Thank you Scott!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the easiest approach would be to draw the pattern manually and make sure that the segments fit the artboard.

There are many ways to do this. You could for example do it like this:

[image]

- Draw one segment of the zigzag line making sure it snaps to the left side of the artboard. Also make sure that it exceeds the artboard so you can add 3 mm bleed.
- Duplicate the segment a fitting amount of times. Select them all and join them.
- Use the *Scale Tool* with the reference point set to the point snapping to the left side of the artboard. Drag a corresponding point to snap to the right side of the artboard.
- Drag a copy of the whole zigzag line and repeat until you have an area covering the height of the artboard including bleed.
- Position and scale the pattern vertically to your liking, choose a fitting stroke weight and colorize it.
- Optionally group the lines and put the group in a clipping mask that includes the bleed to make things look more tidy.

Beware that it's not given that it's possible to make the pattern fit 100% perfectly on the jar. Depending on how your stickers are made, there might be a tiny misalignment when they are cut. Perhaps 1-2 mm. But the misalignment on one side would of course be countered on the other side presuming that the width is precise.

Comment: Thank you so much Wolff! That is really helpful! But it will be difficult if you are trying to replicate a complex pattern. Any idea what we would do in that instance?

Comment: In a way it's the same issue. Take one tile of the pattern. Make its width the width of the document divided by an integer. Duplicate the tile until the artboard is covered.

Comment: @Ali if your pattern is resistant to nonuniform scaling then you need to do it from scratch anyway.

Comment: @joojaa, as I understand it the op just wants the pattern to fit in the sides. I guess it can be cropped in top and bottom. If not then you're right. Then the pattern must be designed specifically for that aspect ratio.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you so much guys!